# SQL insert statement giving unknown column error

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query:

```
INSERT INTO tblstaff(
    staffFirstName,
    staffLastName,
    staffEmail,
    staffPhone,
    staffRole
)
VALUES(
    'Dave',
    'Smith',
    'davesmith@gmail.com',
    '07388917622',
    'Admn'
);
```

is giving me the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'staffFirstname' in 'field list'
```

I am slightly confused because I have written `'staffFirstName'` but the error says `'staffFirstname'`, the actual column name is `staffFirstName`. I'm relatively new to SQL so I'm not really sure what could be causing this error. I'm using phpMyAdmin on an xampp server, not sure if that will help. Any suggestions or useful links?

Thanks,

Zack

Comment: Are you 100% sure the column name is 'staffFirstName'? Those three 'F' s in a row throw a good opportunity for a typo in the CREATE TABLE statement. Just thinking out loud. Try `SELECT staffFirstName FROM tblstaff` and see if you get an error.

Comment: This person also had a similar issue and found that an AFTER INSERT trigger was firing. That would explain the spelling difference. See https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2015/07/16/unobvious-unknown-column-in-field-list-error/

Comment: Ok, I have checked that the column name is 100% correct. Also selecting the column didn't work. I also checked my triggers and found that I had a mistake where the 'N' wasn't capitalised. After fixing that I got the same error but with the correct column name this time.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the trigger that is the issue, this is the trigger that  I have:
`CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON tblstaff
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.staffUsername = CONCAT(left(staffFirstName, 1), staffLastName);`

Comment: Because this is a `BEFORE INSERT`, do staffFirstName and staffLastName need to be prefixed with 'new.'? Please forgive my lack of depth with MySQL.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT ON tblstaff 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET new.staffUsername = CONCAT(left(staffFirstName, 1), staffLastName);
```

This was causing the unknown column error because it was being triggered before inserting the new data.
Simply fixed by add `new.` before `staffFirstName` and `staffLastName`.

Credit to: SQLCliff for finding the solution